# How to handle spaces in S3 File Path in Snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to specify a specific filepath within our S3 buckets for Snowflake ingestion.

```
copy into DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE
  from @SANTABA_ETL_STAGE/Table Name/2020/04/15
  pattern='.*[.]csv'
  on_error = 'continue'
  file_format = csv_etl;
```

But because of the space in this specific filepath I just get this error.

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 36 unexpected '/'.
```

I am not finding any easy way to handle this in the documentation. Is there one?

Comment: Put single quotes around that and rerun. `from '@SANTABA_ETL_STAGE/Table Name/2020/04/15'`

Comment: @JNevill this worked.

Answer (score 1):

While this appears to be [resolved over comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259709/how-to-handle-spaces-in-s3-file-path-in-snowflake#comment108372739_61259709), I just wanted to point out the official documentation that covers this scenario.

Per the [documentation for COPY INTO statements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html), for using any special characters including space the use of single quotes surrounding the stage or location literal is required.

To quote the relevant portion (as of early 2020):

> The URI string for an external location (Amazon S3, Google Cloud
>   Storage, or Microsoft Azure) must be enclosed in single quotes;
>   however, you can enclose any string in single quotes, which allows
>   special characters, including spaces, to be used in location and
>   filenames. For example:
>
> ```sql
> -- Stages
> copy into '@mystage/path 1/file 1.csv' from mytable;
> copy into '@%mytable/path 1/file 1.csv' from mytable;
> copy into '@~/path 1/file 1.csv' from mytable;
>
> -- S3 bucket
> copy into 's3://mybucket 1/prefix 1/file 1.csv' from mytable;
>
> -- Azure container
> copy into 'azure://a.blob.core.windows.net/c/f/file 1.csv' from mytable;
> ```